# TestNG DataProvider with PowerMock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, testng, powermock

I am using Mockito and TestNG for my unit testing.  I have static method to be mocked for which I tried PowerMock.  Unfortunately I am not able to use DataProvider in TestNG along with PowerMock.

Question: Is there any work around to use the DataProvider of TestNG while using PowerMock?

Answer (score 7):

There is a workaround. All parameters of parametrized test method must be declared as of Object type. In test method body you need to cast them to actual types.

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public void testMethodThatUsesPowerMock(Object parameter) {
    mockStatic(SomeClass.class);
    DataType param = (DataType) parameter;
    // ... 
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] data(){
    return new Object[][]{
            new Object[]{new DataType()}
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On the top of PowerMockRunner you can use DataProviderRunner by PowerMockRunnerDelegate, and that you can get your test function arguments implicitly casted.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(DataProviderRunner.class)
// ...
public class Test {
// ...
}
```

https://blog.jayway.com/2014/11/29/using-another-junit-runner-with-powermock/